# tkinter check empty entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, is-empty

I am trying to build a GUI for my `password generator`. Here I have an entry box for the length of password (`inputPasswordLength` which is `int`), which is mandatory. The maximal length is set to 20. Now, if the entry box for password length is empty, a message should be displayed on screen(ResultDisplay). In all posts it is mentioned to compare the length. So I did, and the following error is thrown:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Volumes/HDD/Users/Stephan/PycharmProjects/passwordGeneratorGUIbeta/main.py", line 28, in PasswordGenerationFunc
    if len(passwordLength) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Expected:
If the entry for password length is empty, then show message to input a length.

My code:

```python
# GENERATE PASSWORD FUNCTION
def PasswordGenerationFunc():
    password = None
    passwordLength = inputPasswordLength.get()
    passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
    userName = inputUsername.get()

    if len(passwordLength) == 0:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Length of password is mandatory.", fg="red")
    else:
        if passwordLength > maxPasswordLength:
            ResultDisplay.configure(text="The limit of password length are 20 characters.", fg="red")
        else:
            if userName != "":
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password for " + userName + " is:\n" + password, fg="white")
            else:
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password is: \n" + password, fg="white")
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean: `if passwordLength == 0:`?

Comment: look into tk custom variables - you can assign a `tk.StringVar` to the entry, and call `.get()` to get its value. you can trigger an event to occur when that variable is changed. https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/stringvar-with-examples

Comment: You need to do that check before converting the value to an `int`.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for quick reply. @quamrana no I mean empty. 
I tried following, when InputPasswordLength is still a string:

Comment: `code`
# GENERATE PASSWORD FUNCTION
def PasswordGenerationFunc():
    password = None
    passwordLength = inputPasswordLength.get()
    #passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
    userName = inputUsername.get()

    if passwordLength == 0:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Length of password is mandatory.", fg="red")
    else:
        passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
        if passwordLength > maxPasswordLength:
            ResultDisplay.configure(text="The limit of password length are 20
Nothing happening. 
Error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Now it works without any problems. I don't know if this is dirrty style, but this is how I fixed it:

```python
def PasswordGenerationFunc():
    password = None
    passwordLength = inputPasswordLength.get()
    userName = inputUsername.get()

    if len(passwordLength) == 0:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Length of password is mandatory.", fg="red")
    else:
        passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
        if passwordLength > maxPasswordLength:
            ResultDisplay.configure(text="The limit of password length are 20 characters.", fg="red")
        else:
            if userName != "":
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password for " + userName + " is:\n" + password, fg="white")
            else:
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password is: \n" + password, fg="white")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).